# How can I have the randomly generated number be different each time in the whileloop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, random

The problem I am facing is that the randomly generated number in the value should be random when I do a usercasting. However, it is constantly the same with all the values as soon as the loop starts

```
hp = 1000
Fireball = random.randint(5, 10)
Iceblast = random.randint(0, 20)
Healingtouch = random.randint(5, 10)

MiniBug = 100
bspell1 = random.randint(0, 5)
bspell2 = random.randint(10, 20)
bspell3 = 15
bheal1 = 10
bossturn = random.choice([bspell3, bspell2, bspell1, bheal1])

while MiniBug >= 0:
    usercasting = input("Cast a Spell: ")
    if usercasting == "Fireball":
        print("Your spell did ", Fireball, "damage to the enemy!")
        MiniBug -= Fireball
        print("MiniBug has", MiniBug, "Hp left!")

    if usercasting == "Iceblast":
        MiniBug -= Iceblast
        print("Your spell did ", Iceblast, "damage to the enemy!")
        print("MiniBug has", MiniBug, "Hp left!")

    if usercasting == "Healingtouch":
        hp += Healingtouch
        print("You healed yourself by", Healingtouch, "!")
        print(hp)

    if MiniBug != 0:
        if bossturn == bspell1:
            hp -= bspell1
            print("The enemy attacked you for", bspell1, ",and your current hp is", hp)
        if bossturn == bspell2:
            hp -= bspell2
            print("The enemy attacked you for", bspell2, "and your current hp is", hp)
        if bossturn == bspell3:
            hp -= bspell3
            print("The enemy attacked you for", bspell3, ", and your current hp is", hp)
        if bossturn == bheal1:
            MiniBug += bheal1
            print("The enemy healed himself by", bheal1, "and his hp is", MiniBug)
```

The result I am looking for is to have randomly generated numbers after each "usercasting" and when it is the bossturn.

Comment: You generate random number once before the loop. Then, they are always the same. You should instead use `random.randint` inside the loop whenever you want a random number.

Comment: So basically, the whole game has to be within a loop?

Comment: Not the whole game, but each turn of the game. If you want a different number each turn, each turn you need to roll the dice. Roll the dice means calling `random.randint()`. @MarshallTigerus 's answer explain it in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: In rereading the question, I think I misunderstood.

### *If every time you run the code it uses the same number over and over again*

random.randint(lowerbound, upperbound) returns a number from lowerbound to upperbound, but only when it is called.   So within your while statement, you are not generating additional random numbers within your while statement.  This means that once set, bspell1, bspell2, and bossturn are all going to have unchanging values.

You will need to move bossturn = random.choice([bspell3, bspell2, bspell1, bheal1]) into the while statement, like so:

```
hp = 1000


MiniBug = 100

bspell3 = 15
bheal1 = 10

while MiniBug >= 0:
    // some of these need to be moved into their appropriate if statements, but to generate
    // new values each round, they need to be in the while loop
    bossturn = random.choice([bspell3, bspell2, bspell1, bheal1])
    Fireball = random.randint(5, 10)
    Iceblast = random.randint(0, 20)
    Healingtouch = random.randint(5, 10)
    bspell1 = random.randint(0, 5)
    bspell2 = random.randint(10, 20)
    usercasting = input("Cast a Spell: ")
    if usercasting == "Fireball":
        print("Your spell did ", Fireball, "damage to the enemy!")
        MiniBug -= Fireball
        print("MiniBug has", MiniBug, "Hp left!")

    if usercasting == "Iceblast":
        MiniBug -= Iceblast
        print("Your spell did ", Iceblast, "damage to the enemy!")
        print("MiniBug has", MiniBug, "Hp left!")

    if usercasting == "Healingtouch":
        hp += Healingtouch
        print("You healed yourself by", Healingtouch, "!")
        print(hp)

    if MiniBug != 0:
        if bossturn == bspell1:
            hp -= bspell1
            print("The enemy attacked you for", bspell1, ",and your current hp is", hp)
        if bossturn == bspell2:
            hp -= bspell2
            print("The enemy attacked you for", bspell2, "and your current hp is", hp)
        if bossturn == bspell3:
            hp -= bspell3
            print("The enemy attacked you for", bspell3, ", and your current hp is", hp)
        if bossturn == bheal1:
            MiniBug += bheal1
            print("The enemy healed himself by", bheal1, "and his hp is", MiniBug)
```

### *If every time you run the code it generates the same sequence of numbers*

You may be running into an issue where the seed of the random number generator is the same each time you are running.  You can avoid this by setting a seed dependent on the current time.

```
import random
import time
random.seed(time.clock())
```

This will ensure a pseudo-random first random number that should be fairly close to the random probability of your chosen set.

The reason for this is that random numbers in CS are not really "random" but are determined in part based on a seed value passed in. In this way, you could pass the same seed value to a random number generator and get the same series of numbers from it time and time again (very useful if you want to replicate something that uses a lot of random numbers, like in the game Dwarf Fortress, a seed can be used to create the "same" world again if needed).

Answer (score 0):

There are three general solutions to the non-duplicate 'random' number problem:

- If you want a few numbers from a large range then pick one and reject it if it is a duplicate. If the range is large, then this won't cause too many repeated attempts.
- If you want a lot of numbers from a small range, then set out all the numbers in an array and shuffle the array. Take the random numbers in sequence from the shuffled array.
- If you want a lot of numbers from a large range then use an appropriately sized encryption algorithm. E.g. for 64 bit numbers use DES and encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... in sequence. The output is guaranteed unique because encryption is reversible. Look at [Format Preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) for non-standard sizes.

As @Valentino commented, you are not generating true random numbers.  A raw RNG can always produce a duplicate number.